# rpubchem error - collecting data from pubchem

Tags: pubchem

This is my first try at using R to collect data from pubchem. However i am getting the following error every time for every cid that i have used.

> library("rpubchem")
>
> get.cid(46926545)
>   Error in do.call(cbind, unlist(Filter(function(x) !is.null(x), cvals),  : 
>     second argument must be a list

Can anyone point out what am i doing wrong. The link for the cid is "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/46926545#section=Top"

Comment: got it just needed to update the rpubchem package.